# Nodejs child_process doesnt find commands

Tags: windows, node.js

im trying to execute the folowing with nodejs with Windows

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cp = exec('A:\Programme\node\node.exe',function(err,std,ste) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

i tried replacing node with echo, ipconfig etc.. but i always get the same response:
{ [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }

Im sure that I linked the PATH correctly and I have avoided Spaces.

Does someone have an idea where the Problem could be?

edit

Alright i got, some douchebag removed System32 from PATH.
Added it, now it runs again.
thx for the help.

Comment: I think you need to declare extensions in Windows, such as `.cmd` or `.exe`

Comment: edited it like above, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Does `A:\Programme\node\node.exe` actually exist? Also, try escaping your backslashes: `A:\\Programme\\node\\node.exe`

Comment: The Escaping works with ExecFile, but still no luck with exec. Where does child_process.Exec look when searching for commands?

Comment: @user2741831 does Windows has something similar to `$PATH` on Unix?

Comment: Yeah But im pretty sure that doesn't work. I've expermiented alot with this variable, but i doesn't seam to have any influence on the command.